# Is there any updated documentation about the System.AddIn namespace

Tags: .net, add-in, maf

Everything is in the question, I am trying to make an extensible application by means of add-ins, so other teams can developpe add-in independently of the team that developpe the core application.
While I was looking for documentation I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/add-ins/) which seems to be up to date but the links to the Pipeline requirement are broken. I fount another doc on the MSDN but it's for the [.Net 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384241(v=vs.90).aspx) framework.
And If anyone can point me out to a good tutorial or a book about this framework It will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Have you checked Managed Extension Framework?

Comment: Yes, I want the addins to live in there own process, I think it's more appropriate to get maximum performance when the addin is doing heavy work. The MEF does not support that, correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much out there.  The 3.5 documentation still works and MAF is still functional in .Net 4.6, but there are very few people using it.  Based on feedback from Microsoft, they do not appear to be considering it for a port to .Net Core, so if you have any plans on targeting that in the future, you should look into alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Actually I am starting a new WPF application, I want it to be extensible (to add some custom reporting addins), What you advise me to use as an extension management framework.